# Android and Google Checkout, recieving a notification of payment to my server

Tags: android, google-checkout

I need to create an account on my server for a user when they process a payment through Google checkout.  I will be using a php script to process the payment notification.  Has anyone done this?  Are there some sample PHP scripts already out there?  I read something about the notification history API and the Polling API - the both seem the same to me...

What is the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the best way is to use the History API, although it will take at least 5 minutes for the account to be updated as my server will need to continually poll the server.

Comment: can you please post the exact solution here? I am trying to achieve something similar.